# Get selectedvalue in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-select

I have written a code as follow in the `view.php` file for select,

```
<select name="bloodgroup" id="mem_religion">
    <option value="">- Select Bloodgroup -</option>

    <?php  
    foreach ($bloodgroups as $bloodgroup) { ?>
        <option value="Option"> <?php echo $bloodgroup->bloodgroupname;  ?> 
    <?php } ?>
    </option> 
</select>
```

which gives me the correct result. How can I get the selectedvalue in the `controller.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add form and button to post user selected value. Then in another page, retrieve the value. So:

In view.php:

```
<form method="post" action="/anotherpage">
<select name="bloodgroup" id="mem_religion">
    <option value="">- Select Bloodgroup -</option>

    <?php  
    foreach ($bloodgroups as $bloodgroup) { ?>
        <option value="Option"> <?php echo $bloodgroup->bloodgroupname;  ?> 
    <?php } ?>
    </option> 
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In another page/controller:

```
$bloodgroup_selected = $this->input->post('bloodgroup');
```